# Pri Chadash 496:18 on "eino roeh siman bracha" actual issur or not?

Tags: halacha

The Pri Chadash [Orach Chayim 496:18](http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/tursa.aspx?a=oc_x3086) discusses the degree to which things which are described as "eino roeh siman bracha" are actually assur.  Can someone who knows how to read Hebrew tell me what his conclusion is?   Thanks.

Here is the text:

[image: Image of page of Pri Chadash]

[image: Image of page of Pri Chadash]

Comment: [Welcome to MiYodeya](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501) Eric and thanks for this first question. Great to have you learn with us!

Comment: It seems that he leans towards the conclusion that there is an issur, but isn't so clear to him. Rather, he acknowledges that there is a disagreement and that both the Rambam and the Shulchan Aruch seem to agree that there isn't an issur. The Pri Chadash seems to be makshe and says that there is an issur in selling a sefer Torah if one has no food and working on erev pesach min hamincha ul'ma'alah.

Comment: thanks @chachamNisan.    What does he say about working on erev Shabbos?

Comment: That there is an issur mi'd'rabanan to work min hamincha ulema'aleh on erev shabbat and yom tov; and that this is also so according to the Ran(the Chatam Sofer ztz"l appends that he understood the opposite from the Ran there,though; at the bottom of the page).